# sql query for student schema

Tags: sql, relational

I tried solving the below question.  I just want to make sure if I am correct.

> student(student-name, street, city)
>   offering(department, number, section, time, population)
>   titles(department, number, title)
>   enrollment(student-name, department, number, section)

If I need to find The department, number, section, title, and population for every course section

The SQL query I tried is :

```
select a.department, a.number, a.section,b.title,population as "students"
from offering a ,titles b ,enrollment c,student d
where a.department=b.department
and a.number=b.number
and a.department=c.department
and a.number=c.number
and a.section=c.section
group by a.section
```

Please let me know if I am correct.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Something isn't right with the tables you posted. What you are asking to find is all in the `offering` table.

Comment: No,Its using the title column from the titles and the rest of the columns from the department table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that is correct, because the question doesn't refer to a Student.  The question, as I understand it, is to get a list of all sections that are available, along with its title, which shouldn't need to join to Student. I believe just the Offering and Titles tables would be involved.

```
SELECT a.department, a.number, a.section, b.title, a.population 
FROM offering a INNER JOIN titles b 
ON a.department=b.department and a.number=b.number 
ORDER BY a.department, a.number, a.section
```

Comment: I tried redoing it and think I need to get the department,number,section,title and population for each section. <pre> <code> select a.department, a.number, a.section, b.title, a.population
from offering a,titles b
where a.department=b.department
and a.number=b.number
group by a.section

Comment: Yep, that's looks correct to me.  You can also do it as a join, which I'll put in the answer.  You can use order by instead of group by, since there is no aggregate function.

Comment: Also, FYI, You can/should vote up comments & answers if you've found them useful.  Also, remember to accept the answer that best answered your question.

Comment: Oh okay. I was thinking of using group by because the department,number,title and population should be displayed for each section.Sure I will surely vote the comments.Thank you so much